# make button in tableview section header float/align right programmatically // Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I trying to align of float a UIButton to the right in the section header of a TableView universally.
So far I only managed to add constraints for one screen size...

Here is my code so far:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var headerFrame:CGRect = tableView.frame

    let titelArr: NSArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
    var title = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30))
    title.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20.0)
    title.text = titelArr.objectAtIndex(section) as? String
    title.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


    var headBttn:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.ContactAdd) as UIButton
    headBttn.frame = CGRectMake(320, 10, 30, 30)
    headBttn.enabled = true
    headBttn.titleLabel?.text = title.text
    headBttn.tag = titelArr.indexOfObject(titelArr.objectAtIndex(section))
    headBttn.addTarget(self, action: "addItem:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    var headerView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, headerFrame.size.width, headerFrame.size.height))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 108/255, green: 185/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.9)
    headerView.addSubview(title)
    headerView.addSubview(headBttn)

    return headerView

}
```

How can I make the button float right? The rest of the constraints can stay as they are...

THX for your help!

//Seb

Comment: What do you mean by "float right"? You say you've "added constraints for one screen size", but you haven't added any constraints at all. There's no code here that adds any constraints (if by constraints, you mean NSLayoutConstraints).

Comment: Sorry I'm new to swift! So actually I've no idea how to set constraints programmatically. I want the button to be on the right side of the section header on every device. with the code above `CGRectMake(320, 10, 30, 30)` the button has a fixed position which happens to be on the right side on iPhone 6 portrait. ;-)

Comment: If you have no idea how to do that, then you should read the NSLayoutConstraint class reference, which will include the swift and objective-C methods you need to add the constraints programmatically. You should make an attempt to write the code, and come back with a more specific question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thx to @rdelmar and some research here is the answer if anybody should be interessted ;-)

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var headerFrame = tableView.frame

    var headerView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, headerFrame.size.width, headerFrame.size.height))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 108/255, green: 185/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.9)

    var title = UILabel()
    title.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    title.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20.0)
    title.text = titelArr.objectAtIndex(section) as? String
    title.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    headerView.addSubview(title)

    var headBttn:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    headBttn.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    headBttn.enabled = true
    headBttn.titleLabel?.text = title.text
    headBttn.tag = titelArr.indexOfObject(titelArr.objectAtIndex(section))
    headBttn.addTarget(self, action: "addItem:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    headerView.addSubview(headBttn)

    var viewsDict = Dictionary <String, UIView>()
    viewsDict["title"] = title
    viewsDict["headBttn"] = headBttn

    headerView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "H:|-10-[title]-[headBttn]-15-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

    headerView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "V:|-[title]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    headerView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "V:|-[headBttn]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

    return headerView

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thnx for sharing the amazing answer @Seb. Since there have been some changes made in Swift, which affects your answer. I'll provide an example of how to do the same in Swift 3 and 4:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.frame.size.height))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    let title = UILabel()
    title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    title.text = "myTitle"
    headerView.addSubview(title)

    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle("myButton", for: .normal)
    headerView.addSubview(button)

    var headerViews = Dictionary<String, UIView>()
    headerViews["title"] = title
    headerViews["button"] = button

    headerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[title]-[button]-15-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: headerViews))
    headerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[title]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: headerViews))
    headerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[button]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: headerViews))

    return headerView
}
```